# LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entity Join with static AND condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to convert the following `Join` statement into LINQ TO SQL or LINQ to Entity. I know how to join tables in either implementation; but, i'm struggling with the `AND` clause in the `Join` statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.LastName, 
    p.FirstName
FROM
    dbo.Patient p INNER JOIN dbo.FormPat fp ON p.PatientID = fp.PatientID
    INNER JOIN dbo.TxCyclePhase tcp ON fp.TxCyclePhase = tcp.TxCyclePhaseID AND tcp.Type = 2
```

As far as LINQ to SQL is concerned, I have the followings:

```
 var query = (from p in Context.Set<Patient>().AsNoTracking()
        join fp in Context.Set<PatientForm>().AsNoTracking() on p.Id equals fp.PatientId
        join tcp in Context.Set<TxCyclePhase>().AsNoTracking() on new { fp.TxCyclePhaseId, seconProperty = true } equals new { tcp.Id, seconProperty = tcp.Type == 2 }
        select new
        {
            p.FirstName,
            p.LastName,

        }).Distinct();
```

However, I'm getting an `ArgumentNullException` on the second join statement.

For the LINQ to Entity, I have the followings, however, this is giving me a distinct `IQueryable` of `FormPat`, instead of `Patient`.

```
var patients = Context.Set<Patient>().AsNoTracking()
                .SelectMany(p => p.Forms)
                .Where(fp => fp.Phase.Type == 2)
                .Distinct();
```

Comment: I think my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) will help you. In this case, rule 6: create an anonymous object on each side of the join `equals`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the LINQ to Entity is concerned, I was able to figure it out. I'd still like to know how to do it in LINQ to SQL tho.

I'm using the [EF fluent API](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx). My `Patient` object looks like:

```
public Patient()
        {
            Programs = new HashSet<Program>();
        }
        public virtual ICollection<PatientForm> Forms { get; set; }
```

My `PatientForm` object looks like:

```
public class PatientForm
    {
        public int FormId { get; set; }
        public Patient CurrentPatient { get; set; }
        public TxCyclePhase Phase { get; set; }
    }
```

And the `CyclePhase` object looks like:

```
public TxCyclePhase()
        {
            this.FormPats = new HashSet<PatientForm>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PatientForm> FormPats { get; set; }
```

In the entity configurations, I have the relationships set. So, in the repository, all I have to do is to use the `Any()` function when selecting the `Patient` forms.

```
var patients = Context.Set<Patient>().AsNoTracking()
                .Where(p => p.Forms.Any(f => f.Phase.Type == 2))
                .Distinct();
```